# Post as a fan page on iOS Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, iphone-sdk-3.2

I'm trying to post to a fan page as the fan page, not as the user.

On the old SDK, I simply asked for "me/accounts" and received the access token. Now I can do the same, but I have no way to use that Token, since FBRequest takes its access token from the active session (also, it's a readonly property).

Does anyone knows how to create another session or simply FBRequests with the page token?

Thanks!

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens, when requesting the access token, you can specify that you need the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions in order to post as the page.

Comment: Thanks, I've got the access_token and i'm able to use it if i build NSURLRequest myself. But I'm trying to understand how to do it properly with FBRequest & FBSession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, it's not the cleanest, but it's working:
**Note: Updated for Facebook SDK 3.2+**

```
- (void)postAsFanPageWithToken:(NSString *)aFanPageToken {  
    if (self.selectedFanPage == nil) {
        self.userAccessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
    }
    //Using KVC, since it is a readonly property
    [[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData setValue:aFanPageToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
}

- (void)postAsMe {
    if (self.userAccessToken == nil) {
        return; //Already posting as me
    }
    [[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData setValue:self.userAccessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
    self.userAccessToken = nil;
}

// Make sure you cleanup on logout
- (void)logout {
    self.userAccessToken = nil;
    [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

Comment: For me it's working also, but did you find another better solution?

Comment: No, it's a bit dirty solution, but nothing about this scenario is mentioned on their documentation for the new SDK.

Comment: @NatanR. If you use SDK 3.2 or later, see the last note

Comment: @NatanR. I've updated the code (last update i've forgot self.userAccessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;). Tell me if it works for you..